# Rails 4: Devise redirect after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've made my own authentication function to my controllers that verifies more than just if the user is signed in (if they are a manager, etc.).  The problem I've found is if the person is not signed in and tries to access a page that requires authentication, they successfully get redirected to the sign in page, but after sign in, they do not get sent back to the page they were attempting to access.

I've added the following to `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :store_location

def store_location
    p "storing location"
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  return unless request.get? 
  if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
      request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
  end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session["user_return_to"] || root_path
end

def new_authorize_employee
    if current_user.nil?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: "You must be signed in to access this page." 
    else
        unless current_user.is_employee?
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "You do not have permissions to access this page."
        end
    end
end
```

and in the controller the user is trying to access:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :new_authorize_employee
    ...
end
```

but the user is still redirected to the `root_url` after sign in.  **How do I change the authentication method to allow for redirects to the last page the user attempted to access?**

Comment: Is `session[:previous_url]` and `session["user_return_to"]` supposed to be the same?

Comment: I believe so according to their wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update.  I've also tried both

Answer (score 0):

Devise has a [built in mechanism](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/079ed3b6f8b671acde2dd630d28d21adb010fb3a/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb#L34) for storing the location.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_location!,
    unless: -> { devise_controller? || request.xhr? },
    if: -> { request.get? && is_navigational_format? }

  before_action :authenticate_user!, 
    unless: :devise_controller? # prevents a circular redirect


  private 

  def store_location!
    # from Devise::Controllers::StoreLocation
    # :user is the scope
    store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
  end
end
```

The `:store_location!` callback needs to be placed before `:authenticate_user!` as `:authenticate_user!` will halt the filter chain and redirect before the location can be stored.

The `if:` and `unless:` options let you apply conditions to a controller callback. Note that this is not the same as the `if` and `unless` ruby keywords.

`devise_controller?` and `is_navigational_format?` are Devise helpers. `devise_controller?` should be used to skip a callback in any Devise related controllers instead of blacklisting specific paths. The default navigable formats are `['*/*', :html]`.

There is no need to override [`after_sign_in_path_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L213) as it already uses the stored location:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
end
```

Comment: The wiki for this is really out of date, I keep thinking that I should update it some day but life keeps getting in the way. Feel free to add this to the wiki if you want.