# Devise redirect back to the previous after sign in via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails and devise with AJAX. I implemented [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/rails-5-signup-devise-bootstrap-modal-337a5ed2139d).
Everything works well so far.( I can log in and logout)
I want to redirect the user back to the previous page after successful sign in/sign up.

However, I've tried everything but I could not override `after_sign_in_path_for` method in `ApplicationController/SessionController`.

My ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping, :resource_class
  def resource_name
    :user
  end
  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end
  def resource_class
    User
  end
  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Route:

```
 devise_for :users, path: '', controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions',
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
      passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }
```

Then I realized that even if I typed something like below into SessionsController, I couldn't override `after_sign_in_path_for`;

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    '/somepage'
  end
```

Whatever I write, the system redirects me to the root page.
I've tried [this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update#a-simpler-solution) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944159/devise-redirect-back-to-the-original-location-after-sign-in-or-sign-up) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323180/rails-4-devise-redirect-after-sign-in) links but no hope.
I think my problem is caused by AJAX. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've followed the tutorial, then `create` does not redirect but instead render a js.erb file, which is executed by the browser. That's where you want to change the page

Comment: So what should I do ?